# Creating an analogue of Haskell's Either type in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to create an analogue of the [`Data.Either`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html) type from Haskell in Julia. The following works in v0.5:

```
immutable Either{T, S}
    left :: Nullable{T}
    right :: Nullable{S}
end

either{T, S}(::Type{T}, ::Type{S}, value::T) = Either(Nullable{T}(value), Nullable{S}())
either{T, S}(::Type{T}, ::Type{S}, value::S) = Either(Nullable{T}(), Nullable{S}(value))

a = either(Int64, String, 1)
b = either(Int64, String, "a")

println(a)
println(b)
```

*My question is:* is it possible to make the following constructions work:

```
a = Either{Int64, String}(1)
b = Either{Int64, String}("a")
```

(this way an additional constructor function is not required).

It seems that there should be enough information to construct the object, but so far I could not persuade the compiler to accept any of the variants I tried; e.g. writing

```
immutable Either{T, S}
    left :: Nullable{T}
    right :: Nullable{S}

    Either(value::T) = Either(Nullable{T}(value), Nullable{S}())
    Either(value::S) = Either(Nullable{T}(), Nullable{S}(value))
end
```

results in

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching Either{T,S}(::Nullable{Int64}, ::Nullable{String})
```

Comment: Try putting those constructors outside (after) the definition of the type ("outer constructors").

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it work. `Either{T, S}(value::T) = Either{T, S}(Nullable{T}(value), Nullable{S}())` (and the analogue for `value::S`) produces a warning since `S` is unused in the left-hand side.

Comment: By the way, why do you actually want to do this? This is a rather unnatural thing to do in Julia, that could almost certainly be done better in another way, e.g. multiple dispatch.

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders: I admit, I just started learning Julia, and my intuition may be off. I have a syntactic tree-type structure, and I wanted to use this type to have `Array{Either{Node, Leaf}}` in each tree/subtree object. I know that the built-in `Expr` just uses `Any`, but that seemed a bit too unrestricted to me.

Comment: P.S. Also, it may be useful to return an `Either{Result, Error}` from a function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that I forgot that the default constructor is called with `new`. This variant works:

```
immutable Either{T, S}
    left :: Nullable{T}
    right :: Nullable{S}

    Either(value::T) = new(Nullable{T}(value), Nullable{S}())
    Either(value::S) = new(Nullable{T}(), Nullable{S}(value))
end

a = Either{Int64, String}(1)
b = Either{Int64, String}("a")

println(a)
println(b)
```

Plus, since the default constructor is not exposed, you can't create an object with two non-null values, so the invariant is enforced automatically.